# New Rails sass user having problems with permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

Have never used sass before.

On my production server having to switch `chmod 644 public/*` then run `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` to restart the server.

Once server has rendered the css, I then have to come back and run `chmod 755 public/*` to actually load the css, js and images.

If 755 has higher creds, why does it fail?
actual error is:

`Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /srv/www/mysite.com/myapp/public/stylesheets/custom.css):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Command : `chmod 766 -Rf public/`. it might be work for you

Comment: `chmod 766 -Rf public/` followed by `chmod 755 -Rf public/images/` is what worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got your answer, but if you want to know more of the theory behind it, check this out:

http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc

It's pretty straight-forward... I think it's definitely worth glancing at.

Also, in case you don't already know, the -f option only told chmod to not display a diagnostic message if it couldn't modify the file, so it wasn't totally necessary (though it could be helpful). The -R switch changed the modes of the file hierarchies rooted in the files rather than the files themselves.

Comment: Thanks, it helps.  When it comes to permissions on the server its one of the things that scares me the most.